# Rolling average based on another column

Tags: python, pandas, average, rolling-computation

I have a dataframe df which looks like

| time(float) | value (float) |
| --- | --- |
| 10.45 | 10 |
| 10.50 | 20 |
| 10.55 | 25 |
| 11.20 | 30 |
| 11.44 | 20 |
| 12.30 | 30 |

I need help to calculate a new column called rolling_average_value which is basically the average value of that row and all the values 1 hour before that row such that the new dataframe looks like.

| time(float) | value (float) | rolling_average_value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10.45 | 10 | 10 |
| 10.50 | 20 | 15 |
| 10.55 | 25 | 18.33 |
| 11.20 | 30 | 21.25 |
| 11.44 | 20 | 21 |
| 12.30 | 30 | 25 |

Note: This time column is a float column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can temporarily set a datetime index and apply [`rolling.mean`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.window.rolling.Rolling.mean.html):

```
# extract hours/minuts from float
import numpy as np
minutes, hours = np.modf(df['time(float)'])
hours = hours.astype(int)
minutes = minutes.mul(100).astype(int)
dt = pd.to_datetime(hours.astype(str)+minutes.astype(str), format='%H%M')

# perform rolling computation
df['rolling_mean'] = (df.set_axis(dt)
                        .rolling('1h')['value (float)']
                        .mean()
                        .set_axis(df.index)
                      )
```

output:

```
   time(float)  value (float)  rolling_mean
0        10.45             10     10.000000
1        10.50             20     15.000000
2        10.55             25     18.333333
3        11.20             30     21.250000
4        11.44             20     21.000000
5        12.30             30     25.000000
```

Alternative to compute `dt`:

```
dt = pd.to_datetime(df['time(float)'].astype(str)
                      .str.replace('\d+', lambda x: x.group().zfill(2),
                                   regex=True),
                    format='%H.%M')
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your data frame is sorted by time, you can also use a simple list comprehension to solve your problem. Iterate over `times` and get all indices where the distance from the previous time values to the actual iteration value is less than one (meaning less than one hour) and slice the `value` column that was converted to an array by those indices. Then, you can just compute the mean of the sliced array:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"time": [10.45, 10.5, 10.55, 11.2, 11.44, 12.3],
    "value": [10, 20, 25, 30, 20, 30]}     
)

times = df["time"].values
values = df["value"].values

df["rolling_mean"] = [round(np.mean(values[np.where(times[i] - times[:i+1] < 1)[0]]), 2) for i in range(len(times))]
```

If your data frame is large, you can compile this loop in C/C++ too make it significantly faster:

```py
from numba import njit

@njit
def compute_rolling_mean(times, values):
    return [round(np.mean(values[np.where(times[i] - times[:i+1] < 1)[0]]), 2) for i in range(len(times))]
    
df["rolling_mean"] = compute_rolling_mean(df["time"].values, df["value"].values)
```

Output:

```
    time    value  rolling_mean
0   10.45   10     10.00
1   10.50   20     15.00
2   10.55   25     18.33
3   11.20   30     21.25
4   11.44   20     21.00
5   12.30   30     25.00
```